# UI page for editing and maintaining Profile settings for a User

Tags: asp.net, security, profile

In asp.net Webforms apps, is there not any kind of maintenance UI page to edit and maintain the Profile properties of a User (I'm using VS2008 and the Web Application template), like in the WSAT Web Site Administratration Tool where you already can edit the basic Membership and Role properties for a User? I'm using the basic SQL Express data tables and the basic Membership and Role providers, and now I want to begin using the Profile provider to store and access additional properties for each User I create an account for. For instance, when I create a new User and assign them to a Role(s) on my web app, I use the WSAT tool, and now I also need to set certain Profile properties for them too. Is the only way to set these properties is programmatically? Surely there is an Admininstrative type of UI page for this so you can quickly view and edit Profile properties for a User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roles and Membership conform to a standard schema that you can easily create a static form for editing. Profile details are dynamic based on your configuration settings - and building dynamic forms can be a bit tricky.

On top of that, the default Profile provider stores all the profile information in one concatenated field, so you'd end up with a list of comma-separated values if they went for a really basic form.